# How to echo the value of radio button when edit

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, radio-button, sql-update

I knew this question has been asked before. But I tried all the solution there still can't get the output. This is what I did:- (actually the problem just in my update page) and the problem is just with the radio button, I just want the radio button to carry the value and checked it with the value from database

update_page.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$item_code= $_GET['item_code'];
$sel = mysql_query("select * from `table 14` where Item_Code='$item_code'");
$get_sel = mysql_fetch_array($sel); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function getting()
{
var agree=confirm("Confirm Update?");
if (agree)
document.myform2.submit2();

else
return false;
}
</script>
<center>
<h2 class="back" width='1400px'>Update Item Info</h2>

<div class="content">
<p style="margin-top:20px; font-size:20px;"><b><?php echo 
$get_sel['Item_Code']; ?></b></p>
<br />

<div id="main">

<form name="myform2" action="admin_update_process.php?item_code=<?php echo 
$get_sel['Item_Code'];?>" method="POST" >
<table>

<tr>
    <th>Vendor</th>     
    <th>Vendor Desc</th>
    <th>Item Code</th>
    <th>Item Decs</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="vendor" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo $get_sel['Vendor']; ?>' 
/></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="vendor_desc" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo 
$get_sel['Vendor_Desc']; ?>' /></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="item_code" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo $get_sel['Item_Code']; 
?
>' /></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="item_desc" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo $get_sel['Item_Desc']; 
?
 >' /></td>
<tr>
    <th>CUR</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>COO</th>
    <th>COO Material</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="cur" class="input_teks_upd" 
size="30px" value='<?php echo $get_sel['Cur']; ?>' /></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="price" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo $get_sel['Price']; ?>' 
/></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="coo" class="input_teks_upd" 
size="30px" value='<?php echo $get_sel['Coo']; ?>' /></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="coo_material" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo 
$get_sel['Coo_Material']; ?>' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>PROD L/Time</th>
    <th>MOQ</th>
    <th>Part name/Material</th>
    <th>Normal Shipping Mode</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="prod_l_time" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo 
$get_sel['Prod_L_Time']; ?>' /></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="moq" class="input_teks_upd" 
size="30px" value='<?php echo $get_sel['Moq']; ?>' /></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="part_name" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo $get_sel['Part_Name']; 
?
>' /></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="normal_shipping" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo 
$get_sel['Normal_Shipping']; ?>' /></td>
<tr>
    <th>Shipping Lead Time</th>
    <th>Common/Customize for Onkyo</th>
    <th>Marker Part No</th>
    <th>Aprroval Spec (YES/NO)</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="ship_lead" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo 
$get_sel['Shipping_Lead']; ?>' /></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="common" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo 
$get_sel['Common_Customize']; ?>' /></td>
<td><input autofocus type="text" required name="maker_part" 
class="input_teks_upd" size="30px" value='<?php echo 
$get_sel['Maker_Part_No']; ?>' /></td>
<td><input autofocus type="radio" name="approval" value="YES" 
    <?php echo ($approval=='YES') ? " checked " : "";?>> YES
    <input autofocus type="radio" name="Green_Document" value="NO"
    <?php echo($approval=='NO') ? " checked " : "";?>>NO <br/>
</td>
    <th>Green Document (YES/NO)</th>
    <th>Upload Approval Spec</th>
    <th>Upload Green Document</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input autofocus type="radio" name="Green_Document" value="YES" 
    <?php echo ($Green_Document=='YES') ? " checked " : "";?>> YES
    <input autofocus type="radio" name="Green_Document" value="NO"
    <?php echo($Green_Document=='NO') ? " checked " : "";?>>NO <br/>
</td>
<td><input  type="file" name="file_approval"/></td>
<td><input  type="file" name="file_green"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Confirm Update Data" 
class="admin_button" onClick="return getting();" />

</form>


</div>
</div>  

</center>
```

update_query.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
extract($_POST);

$item_code=$_GET['item_code'];

if($item_code==''){

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('No details entered. Update Fail.')";
echo "</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; 
url=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'>";

}
else{
$pro1 = mysql_query("update `table 14` set Vendor='$vendor',Vendor_Desc='$vendor_desc',Item_Code='$item_code',Item_Desc='$item_desc', Cur='$cur', Price='$price', Coo='$coo', Coo_Material='$coo_material', Prod_L_Time ='$prod_l_time', 
Moq='$moq', Part_Name='$part_name', Normal_Shipping='$normal_shipping', Shipping_Lead='$ship_lead', Common_Customize='$common',
Maker_Part_No='$maker_part', Approval_Spec='$approval', Green_Document='$Green_Document' where Item_Code = '$item_code'"); //this the part I send the green_document

if($pro1)
    {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Item Info Successfully Updated')";
echo "</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'>";
}

else
{

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Failed to update, try again')";
echo "</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; 
url=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'>";
}
}
}
mysql_close()
```

Comment: Did you tried `if($green_document=='YES'){?> checked="checked" <? }?>`

Comment: @Naga yes, already do that, but still can't.

Comment: Its unclear your actual question. Could you provide an example of what you want to happen? Explain it please. Where does `$green_document` come from? Why do you have two sets of the same radios? What is the flow and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm creating 1 update page for the user, so when the user open this update page, I'll show them all the previous record (from the databse) to them , so they can update any column. So when its come to radio button, I want the radio button to show the record from database, (If previously they choose "YES" now if they open the update page, the radio button there will checked "YES" for them. @IncredibleHat  (Am I answering your question?)

Comment: It does, but you still have not said where `$green_document` is assigned. The code you have is close. Naga mentioned the extra `checked="checked"`, and jerome showed you a ternary way. But I believe the issue is with the variable itself isn't assigned right from your database.

Comment: $green_document is assigned to another update_process.php where I put all the query for updates. But the update doing very well. no problem with the update, just that the radio button in add_page doesn't show the checked value from database is we reopen the page @IncredibleHat

Comment: Right.... so please.... show us how you are grabbing the data and utilizing the variables to use for this page load.

Comment: @NazirahAnwar Wow, it is really hard to follow your question details via comments.  Please take the time to clarify your question via an Edit.  Do you need the `id` attributes on your input tags?  Have you echo'ed your `$green_document` value to ensure that it is holding the expected value?  (please clear out your comments, and update your question)

Comment: I've edited my question above with attaching my full coding, can u please help me :( @IncredibleHat

Comment: @IncredibleHat you were right the variable was not declared.  Please vote offtopic typo.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had gone to bed and did not see the update. In addition to this just being a non-reproducible typo error... you really should stop using the `mysql_*` functions as they are depreciated, and outright removed by php7. Move to `mysqli_*` or better, the class method or PDO. Then top it off with some `prepared` statements to protect your database from sql injection attacks. Take it easy!

Comment: ok @IncredibleHat I'll change my code very soon thx for the info..really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are almost there. Check this out, i just made some adjustment on your code including echoing the `checked` attribute

```html
    <b>Green Document (YES/NO):</b>
    <input type="radio"    name="green_document"  value="YES">Yes
    <input type="radio"    name="green_document"  value="NO">No<br>
    <br />

   <td><input type="radio" name="green_document" value="YES" id="YES" 
        <?php echo($green_document=='YES') ? " checked " : "";?>> YES
        <input type="radio" name="green_document" value="NO" id="NO"
        <?php echo($green_document=='NO') ? " checked " : "";?>>NO <br/>
    </td>
```

Comment: not sure why I get this error " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' " @jerome

Comment: @IncredibleHat I tried that but still can't get the output.Please someone help me

Comment: Yea i forgot to remove that `if`. I've edited the answer pls check

Comment: @NazirahAnwar I've edited again. Srry for inconvinience

Comment: This time I don't get the error but still both of the radio button is unchecked @jerome

Comment: where do you get the value of `$green_document` ? there is something wrong in your variable

Comment: My god, I'm really sorry If I made u guys confuse, actually, I tried to call the green_document from my database, I got 4 page, add_user.php (which inside the form I created the radio button name= $green_document) and addprocess.php where I send the query to mysql database , update.php where I created another radio button for updates propose and tried to checked them with the value from database as send before through addprocess.php and my last page is update.php where I send query to mysql to update the database in mqsql. @jerome

Comment: Can you show how do you add a value in `$green_document` ? and how did you pass it `Add_page.php`

Comment: I've edited my question above with attaching my full coding, can u please help me :(

Comment: @NazirahAnwar in your `update_page.php` you did not specify the value of variable `$green_document` hence it is `null` so whatever you compare to it always gives false.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get u..how to do that? @jerome

Comment: @NazirahAnwar you need to declare the value of  `$green_document`. Before you proceed to your `if` statement.

Comment: can u give me an example (a line of code maybe)..so sorry I though I declare everything well @jerome

Comment: @NazirahAnwar something like this `$green_document = $get_sel['Green_Document'];` do that before the `<td>` of your `radio buttons`

Comment: OMG this is so funny, how could I forgot to declare that..my goddddd, thx for save my life @jerome

Comment: @NazirahAnwar no pressure. happy coding